# incomplete reading data serial port

Tags: visual-c++, serial-port

I want to read 6 data sensors from arduino to VC++ with "handshaking" methods, I send "1" to arduino then this device will send the data to PC.
My data format is:
 `&data0,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5%`

But when I read it with VC++ data always incomplete, even thought the size of buffer is enough for all the data

here is the snapshot of my vC++ program, I put it on timer event

```
    DWORD nbytes;
    char buffer[24];

    //Read Sensors

    if(!WriteFile( hnd_serial, "1", 1, &nbytes, NULL )){KillTimer(cTimer1);MessageBox(L"Write Com Port fail!");return;}
    Sleep(5);
    if(!ReadFile( hnd_serial, buffer, 23, &nbytes, NULL )){KillTimer(cTimer1);MessageBox(L"Read Com Port fail!");return;}
    Sleep(50);
```

I have changed the baud rate but the result still the same.
but If I reduce one data such as data5 (become 5 sensors), data is complete.
Have I do something wrong with my program?

Comment: Did you check the arduino  receive "1" or not?

Comment: yes the arduino is receiving 1, and send the data, but the data is not complete (3 last data)

Comment: how many bytes of each data? (data0, data1,..)

Comment: data is between 0-255 each sensor

Answer (score 0):

You can put your ReadFile() function inside a do-while loop.

```
do{
    if(!ReadFile( hnd_serial, buffer, 23, &nbytes, NULL )){
        //Process error
        break;
    }
    if (nbytes>= 6)
    {
        //Put your flag - or process here
        break;
    }
}while(nbytes);
```

The ReadFile() only returns the current buffer status, it will not wait for  receiving full of your expected data

Comment: Thank you, but the reading of the buffer never reach the end of the data (%). Might be because the "buffer" of the serial port is limited.

Comment: you can try put a delay 1s timer before call ReadFile to check this situation

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what baud rate you're working with.

You also don't say what, if any, receive timeouts have been set.

Lets assume it's 9600 that means the port transfers 960 bytes per second. So  just over 1 millisecond per byte.

If your sleep(5) is supposed to wait for the "1" to be sent AND for the the data to come back then you ought to wait long enough for all of your bytes to be transferred. Assuming timeouts are set so that the ReadFile returns immediately with whatever bytes are in the RX buffer then there's a chance you're reading too quickly.

Try a bigger delay.